# To get selected item in dynamic control -combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have created a `ComboBox` dynamically, but I need to select the value from `SelectedIndexChanged`. I am getting the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
private ComboBox TimeIntervel;
int Stimer; 
public void set control()
{
    ComboBox TimeIntervelCmb = new ComboBox();
    TimeIntervelCmb.Location = new Point(50,70);
    TimeIntervelCmb.Name = "ComboBoxTime";
    TimeIntervelCmb.Size = new Size(80, 100);
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("500");
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("1000");
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("2000");
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("3000");
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("4000");
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("5000");
    TimeIntervelCmb.Items.Add("6000");
    TimeIntervelCmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(TimeIntervel_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.Controls.Add(TimeIntervelCmb);
}

private void TimeIntervel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (TimeIntervel.SelectedItem  != null)// Object reference not set to an instance of an object.-Error
        {
            Stimer = int.Parse(TimeIntervel.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: When the control is 1st constructed an event occurs before any items are added.  You have to ignore this 1st event.  Test for Count to be > 0.

Comment: how can we ignore 1st event in IF loop

Comment: @user2944173 1. You don't have to; 2. Please don't call it a loop;

Answer (score 1):

You create a `ComboBox` in a local variable named `TimeIntervelCmb` and never assign it to `TimeIntervel`, therefore `TimeIntervel` will always be null.

Add this line:

```
TimeIntervel = TimeIntervelCmb;
```

Or check the `ComboBox` instance that raises the event:

```
ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
if (combo .SelectedItem  != null)
// etc ...
```